# Send params in header and get them in server side - java

Tags: java, server, header, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey and I want to get params from the header of request;

Here is my java server side code:

```
@GET
@Path("/usersForMobile")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8" })
public Response getUsersForMobile(@Context UriInfo info) {  
    String rashutId ;
    String userName ;
    String password;
    List<User> inspectorList= new ArrayList<User>();

    try {

         rashutId = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("rashutId");
         userName = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("userName");
         password = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("password");
         inspectorList = LoginService.getInspectorsList(userName,password,rashutId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }

        if(!inspectorList.isEmpty())
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new UsersResponse(inspectorList, true)).build();
        else
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("No inspectors found").build();

    }
}
```

Until now I got the params from url, but it's not reliable way, so I decided to pass them in the header, how can I get them from request header?

thanks!

Comment: And how is this related to Spring, you are using JAX-RS (Jersey) ...

Comment: you right... sorry I'll edit it.

Comment: Do you have any idea about my problem?

Comment: You aren't using anything from Spring MVC... I suggest a read of the Jersey lib on how to access headers.

Comment: Ok can you edit my question?Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use an @HeaderParam("paramName") to get the HTTPHeader param e.g

```
public Response getUsersForMobile(@Context UriInfo info, @HeaderParam("paramName")String  paramValue)
```

or use the context you have

```
String paramValue = info.getRequestHeader("paramName").get(0);
```

Comment: I got this compilation error:"Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameter"

Comment: You're missing the type declaration before paramValue

Comment: @peeskillet thanks, yes i updated the answer.

 Add the string before parameterValue if you are going by Approach 1. If you are going by 2, then don't change anything in method signature.

Comment: Another error:The method getRequestHeader(String) is undefined for the type UriInfo. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked your Context type. Add another Context for http header 

@Context HttpHeaders headers and then call the method on these headers if you don't want to add single header parameter (approach 1)