# Build a REST endpoint and SOAP with one implementation in Java EE

Tags: java, rest, soap, jax-rs, jax-ws

So I'm trying to annotate a method with both JAX-RS and JAX-WS, I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871815/soap-and-rest-webservice-with-one-implementation-in-java-ee) and FWIW it **really isn't a good idea** however I got stuck when trying to implement this

```
@GET
@Path("loginWithEmail")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@WebResult(name = "response")
@WebMethod(operationName = "loginWithEmail")
public BaseResponse loginWithEmail(
        @WebParam(name = "sessionId", header = true) String sessionId,
        @WebParam(name = "email") String email,
        @WebParam(name = "password") String password) {
System.out.println("Session Id is " + sessionId);
}
```

Passing the sessionId header works perfectly for the SOAP but doesn't for REST - any ideas why and how to resolve?

PS - This is purely experimental and won't be using such in production - just curious to know how to set header - Thank you :)

Comment: SessionId should be HTTP header param and not a webparam which is a SOAP parameter annotation and not rest parameter. Inject http header parameter for REST as well...

I recently made a post on how to access http header in REST 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756435/send-params-in-header-and-get-them-in-server-side-java/43756757#43756757

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined any parameter for restful service you need to make **@queryparan or @pathparam or @bean ..** it may work

Comment: I don't think so the @GET
@Path("loginWithEmail")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) are JAX-RS

Comment: where is the annotation of jax-rs for the parameters

Comment: I'm not passing any path or querying anything so I don't need/have them